# Erron no visualg (senao)

Tags: visualg, portugol

o visualg diz que tem erro no senao , mas nao to vendo nenhum, se alguem puder ajudar agradeço

```
algoritmo "supercontador"

var
   cont, num : inteiro
inicio
  Repita

     escreval ("  =====================  ")
     escreval ("         menu            ")

     escreval (" =====================   ")
     escreval  (" [1]De 1 a 10            ")
     escreval  (" [2]De 10 a 1            ")
     escreval  (" [3]Sair                 ")
     escreval (" =====================    ")

           escreval("escolha um numero")
           leia(num)
      escreval("====================================")
      se (num=1) entao
       cont<-1
         repita
            escreva (cont, "..." )
            cont<-cont+1
         ate (cont>10)
      fimse

     senao
        se  (num=2) entao
           cont<-10
          repita
              escreva(cont,"...")
                cont<-cont-1
          ate (cont<1)
         fimse
     


  Ate (num=3 )
     escreval("voce saiu !!!")




fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro foi bem clara: SENAO sem SE correspondente.
A sintaxe do visualg para estruturas condicionais aninhadas é mais ou menos como o exemplo a seguir:

```
se(condicao) entao
...
senao
se
...
fimse
fimse
```

Note que existe um FIMSE para cada SE.

Adaptando no seu código, ficaria assim:

```
se (num=1) entao


cont<-1
     repita
        escreva (cont, "..." )
        cont<-cont+1
     ate (cont>10)


 senao
    se  (num=2) entao
       cont<-10
      repita
          escreva(cont,"...")
            cont<-cont-1
      ate (cont<1)
     fimse
     fimse
```

Se executar o codigo, verá que existe outro erro de sintaxe na estrutura de repetição ATE.
A sintaxe é mais ou menos como o seguinte exemplo:

```
para variavel de indexDeInicio ate indexDeTermino faca
...
fimpara
```

Adaptando essa estrutura no seu código, ficaria assim:

```
para num de 0 Ate 3 faca
escreval("voce saiu !!!")
fimpara
```